# Java Socks Proxy Socket Error

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, socks

I am trying to create a http request through a SOCKS (v4 / v5) proxy in Java. After reading about socks communication protocol on WikiPedia, I have put togheter this piece of code:

```
Socket sock = new Socket();
InetSocketAddress remoteProxyAddress = new InetSocketAddress(proxy ip, proxy port);
sock.connect(remoteProxyAddress, connTimeout);

InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();

out.write(0x04);
out.write(0x01);
out.write((endpoint.getPort() >> 8) & 0xff);
out.write((endpoint.getPort() >> 0) & 0xff);
out.write(endpoint.getAddress().getAddress());
out.write(0x0);
out.flush();
```

And here comes the part where I read from the proxy server. The problem is that the response is always "-1".

I have tried the proxy on Firefox and it works perfect. So... the problem is in my app.

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why? Java already supports SOCKS proxying. You don't have to write it yourself. See the Javadoc/Guide to Features/Networking.

Comment: Yes... it already supports SOCKS, but it is on the entire VM. I need multiple simultaneous connections on different proxy servers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that the server you are connecting to supports only Socks v5 protocol?

There is everything fine with your connection request. Your code should be working provided the server enabled for v4. I am using very similar implementation absolutely successfuly.

Also you should take a look at this [Socket()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.Proxy%29) constructor - it might be sufficient for your needs. It exist in both JRE 1.6 and JRE 1.7

Comment: this is really strange. did you try Sun's impmementation?

Comment: Could you check the actual values of endpoint.getPort() and endpoint.getAddress().getAddress() just in the beginning of this code?

Comment: One more thing. Does endpoint.getAddress().getAddress() return ipv4 address?

Comment: I've checked the output with a packet sniffer. All the data sent before actual http request is identical (I mean between my app and Firefox).

Comment: @IonutUngureanu what about server's response?

Comment: Server response is always "-1".

Comment: @IonutUngureanu Would you like to show me the captured traffic in chat?

Comment: Let me explain shortly... I've captured Firefox traffic, then I've made a "connect" request like above. My request was identical with Firefox first 9 bytes. So... all the data is sent. But the server fails to respond with a valid response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17337/discussion-between-serge-and-ionut-ungureanu)